# 'Check all boxes' Check box in Python

Tags: user-interface, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

Using python and tkinter I have an app that dynamically creates lots of check boxes (around 40) and i would like to add another one that preceeds them that can **check all** of the checkboxes

An example of this is in email... when you want to delete large quanitities of email you can check the 'Select all' checkboxs.

My question is how can I add this functionality to my python GUI app. I think it's to do with `chk_btn.config(state="")` but im not sure

Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating Checkboxes dynamically is usually a bad idea.  It can lead to problems such as losing track of the buttons.  However, this mini script I wrote should demonstrate how to do what you want:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# Create a dictionary where the keys are the checkbuttons
# and the values are their BooleanVars
buttons = dict()
for _ in xrange(10):
    buttons[Checkbutton(root)] = BooleanVar()

for button in buttons:
    # Place each button on the window
    button.grid()
    # Hook each button up to its BooleanVar
    button.config(variable=buttons[button])
    # Set each BooleanVar to True
    buttons[button].set(True)

# I printed this just to show what is going on
print buttons

root.mainloop()
```

What saves me from losing track of the buttons is the dictionary I made to store them and their BooleanVars.  If you want to access either a button or its variable, you can find it in that dictionary.

Comment: I take it the key part here is `buttons[button].set(True)` does this change the variable assigned to the check buttons also?

Comment: @DCA- Yes to both of your statements.  `buttons[button]` yields the variable (BooleanVar) that goes with `button`.  I made the dictionary to have its keys be the button instances and the values to be their appropriate BooleanVars.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested - ignoring the answer i was given (whoops), used this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root).grid()

class state:
    def read_states():
        arry = list(map(lambda var: var.get(), states))
        for n in range(len(arry)):
            print(arry[n])
        print('----')
    def change_states(x):
        for n in range(len(folder1)):
            x[n].set(1)
    def clear_states():
        for n in range(len(states)):
            states[n].set(0)
states = []
bgs = []
folder1 = []
folder2 = []
folder_break = []
for n in range(10):
    var = IntVar()
    chk = Checkbutton(frame, text=n+1, variable=var)
    chk.grid(row=n+3)
    if n < 5:
        folder1.append(var)
    else:
        folder2.append(var)
    states.append(var)


btn_2 = Button(frame, text='Change', command=lambda w=folder1: state.change_states(w))
btn_2.grid(row=1)
btn_3 = Button(frame, text='Change2', command=lambda w=folder2: state.change_states(w))
btn_3.grid(row=1, column=1)
btn_4 = Button(frame, text='Clear', command=state.clear_states)
btn_4.grid(row=2)
btn = Button(frame, text='GO', command=state.read_states)
btn.grid(row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

this gave me more freedom and control and was inspired by the first answer.

Thanks again for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it using a checkbutton to select/deselect all checkboxes:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def select_clear_states():
    global Vars, all_states
    states = all_states.get()

    if states == 0:
        for i in range(len(Vars)):
            Vars[i].set(0)
    if states == 1:
        for i in range(len(Vars)):
            Vars[i].set(1)

Vars = []

root = tk.Tk()

all_states = tk.IntVar()
select_all = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "select/deselect all", 
                            variable = all_states, command = select_clear_states)
select_all.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 1)

for n in range(10):

    var = tk.IntVar()
    Vars.append(var)
    checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = n+1, variable= Vars[n])
    checkbox.grid(row = n+1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 1)     

root.mainloop()
```

I know it's not very clean to use global variables but I'm currently to lazy to get into OOP.