# How to turn on or off all checkbuttons with one button python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 27 checkbuttons on one tab of a PAGE GUI dialog and I would like to be able to turn them all on or off with one other checkbutton on the same tab. They are not in a grid.

SOLVED: Here is how I did it (showing it for just the first two of the 27 checkbuttons). Tch28 is the "All" checkbutton which has the command all()

```
def all():
    a1 = tch28.get()
    if a1 == "1":
        tch1.set(1)
        tch2.set(1)

    else:
        tch1.set(0)
        tch2.set(0)
```

Here is what the Checkbuttons look like . As you can see, they are in frames and not organized in a simple grid.

[image]

Comment: please add a sample of code, and add what you have tried to solve the problem

Comment: Rachel, Thanks for your response, hope I haven't given too much information. :-)

Comment: look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41302692/1675954

Comment: Rachel, I am looking at that answer, but have to figure out how to use that method without the gridded checkboxes. My dialog is more complex than the example. You may have noticed that I am a beginner...

Comment: is there a particular reason why you're not using a grid?

Comment: Please see the picture above...

Comment: you'd have to offer a 'Select All' option in each frame.. that's the most viable way I would suggest doing it. Otherwise it's making life very hard. It's also more user-friendly. Btw, it's about 20 to midnight where I am so I'm not going to post again tonight. Best of luck..

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help!

Comment: No problem :) ..

Comment: @CPMAN if you solved your question, it would be a good idea, to actually post the answer as an answer and leave the original untouched. This way, others can see, that the problem is solved

Comment: @user8408080 Understood, sorry, I couldn't figure out how to put the code and dialog in an answer box. Also, in the original I show a bunch of code that turned out to be irrelevant to the solution. I am new to this forum and will try to do better next time.

Comment: No problem. Point of this site is: You post your question general enough, so that others can benefit from it and the answer still solves your problem. So if you can break down your problem to something useful, write that as a question and answer it. If you can't or think, that your question is *only* useful for you, it may be better to delete it completely. Stackoverflow is meant to "reduce the signal to noise ration of the internet". Have a nice day :)